# Binding <Print Screen> key to a function on Solaris

Tags: emacs, elisp

I found this code:

```
(w32-register-hot-key [snapshot])
(global-set-key [snapshot] 'some-function)
```

Unfortunately, this works on a windows machine. 
I couldn't find a way to rebind the print screen key on Solaris.

Answer (score 1):

I found out that I needed to disable the shortcut from the "keyboard preferences" first.
After that it becomes key F22 and easily assigned in .emacs.

Answer (score 0):

You first must find the key's name. You can do this with <kbd>Ctrl-h c</kbd>, which prompts you with

> Describe key (or click or menu item):

Then press the key in question,  <kbd>Print screen</kbd>. 
Emacs responds with something like

> <print> is undefined

So, `print` is the name we're after.

To assign a function to this `print` key, you use the snippet, you've found

```
(global-set-key [print] 'some-function)
```

or

```
(global-set-key [print] (lambda() (interactive) (do something fancy)))
```

if it is more than a simple function call.

Comment: Hi Olaf. Thanks for the answer. I did actually do that but no variable names showed up.

Comment: Then the key is already captured by the window system. On my Ubuntu system, `print` is bound to taking a screen shot. I had to unbind the print key, before I could do this in emacs.